# how to extract particular value from JSON in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to extract only 'phaseValue' part from below json and store that into array.

```
{  
   "templateName":"TemplateExample",
   "phaseExecutions":{  
      "PRE":[  
         {  
            "phaseType":"text",
            "phaseValue":"enter your name"
         },
         {  
            "phaseType":"number",
            "phaseValue":"enter your mobile number"
         },
         {  
            "phaseType":"email",
            "phaseValue":"enter your email"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Above data I am getting from below code

```
getTemplateByName():any
{


    this.httpService.get('http://localhost:57611/Api/Employee/GetTemplateByName/'+this.selectedTemplate).subscribe(  
          data => {  
           this.templateInJsonFormat = data;   
           this.getTemplateFromSubscribe(this.templateInJsonFormat);
          }
       );
    }

    getTemplateFromSubscribe(temp:any)
    {
         this.finalTemplateFromSubscribe = temp;  
         console.log(this.finalTemplateFromSubscribe);    
    }
```

I am using typescript 3.5.3. Please help.

Comment: use map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2htffv)**

```
result = []

 this.httpService
  .get(
    "http://localhost:57611/Api/Employee/GetTemplateByName/" +
      this.selectedTemplate
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.templateInJsonFormat = data;
    this.result = this.templateInJsonFormat.phaseExecutions.PRE.map(x => x.phaseValue)
    this.getTemplateFromSubscribe(this.templateInJsonFormat);
  });
```

Comment: Please have a look at updated code in my question.I am getting that json data from api.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: It is showing error: [ts] Property 'phaseExecutions' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Answer (score 6):

`const arr = object.phaseExecutions.PRE.map(item => item.phaseValue)`

Comment: Please have a look at updated code in my question.I am getting that json data from api.

Comment: Yes, this can be applied anywhere regardless of specific implementation and code organization.

Answer (score 5):

Live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-m9nv6q

```
const data = 
{  
   "templateName":"TemplateExample",
   "phaseExecutions":{  
      "PRE":[  
         {  
            "phaseType":"text",
            "phaseValue":"enter your name"
         },
         {  
            "phaseType":"number",
            "phaseValue":"enter your mobile number"
         },
         {  
            "phaseType":"email",
            "phaseValue":"enter your email"
         }
      ]
   }
}

const arr = data.phaseExecutions.PRE.map(p=>p.phaseValue);
```

I recommend you to take a look to the .map() documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Please have a look at updated code in my question.I am getting that json data from api.

Answer (score 5):

```
obj = {  
   "templateName":"TemplateExample",
   "phaseExecutions":{  
      "PRE":[  
         {  
            "phaseType":"text",
            "phaseValue":"enter your name"
         },
         {  
            "phaseType":"number",
            "phaseValue":"enter your mobile number"
         },enter code here
         {  
            "phaseType":"email",
            "phaseValue":"enter your email"
         }
      ]
   }
}

var phaseValueArr = obj.phaseExecutions.PRE.map(x => x.phaseValue);
```

phaseValueArr is the required array

Comment: Please have a look at updated code in my question.I am getting that json data from api.